# How to write/append text to the bottom of n SQL script?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the need to add/append text(`SQL`) to the bottom of an existing `script`.

I have a `STORED PROCEDURE` that generates `INSERT statements` for me. They are quit allot, so at the moment i copy and past them in the desired `scripts`.

This is basically what the SQL looks like:

```
SELECT '' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'EXECUTE [procSystemAppEntity_InsertOrUpdate] ' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + ' @SystemUID = @SystemUID' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) 
+ ',@SystemAppCode = @SystemAppCode' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) 
+ ',@SystemAppEntityTypeCode = N''' + saet.[SystemAppEntityTypeCode] + '''' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) 
+ ',@SystemAppEntityUID = '''+ CAST((SELECT NEWID()) AS nvarchar(max)) + '''' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) 
+ ',@SystemAppEntityCode = ''' + tab.name + '''' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) 
+ ',@SystemAppEntityName = N''' + tab.name + '''' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) 
+ ',@TableName = N''' + tab.name + '''' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) 
+ ',@TableKeyColumnName = N''' + tab.name + 'ID''' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) 
+ ',@TableKeyCodeColumnName = N''' + tab.name + 'Code''' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) 
+ ',@ManagedAssemblyName = N''' + CASE WHEN @SystemAppEntityManagedAssemblyName IS NULL THEN '' ELSE @SystemAppEntityManagedAssemblyName END + '''' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) 
+ ', @ManagedNamespace = N''' + CASE WHEN @SystemAppEntityManagedNamespace IS NULL THEN '' ELSE @SystemAppEntityManagedNamespace END + '''' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) 
+ ', @ManagedClassName = ''' + tab.name + '''' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) 
+ ', @IsMultiple = ' + CAST(@IsMultiple AS varchar(1)) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) 
+ ', @IsCodeGenerated = 1' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) 
+ ', @IsActive = 1' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) 
+ ', @SystemAppUserID = @CreationSystemAppUserID ' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + '; '
FROM sys.tables tab INNER JOIN
    [SystemAppEntityType] saet ON saet.[IsMultipleEntity] = CASE WHEN RIGHT(tab.name, 1) = 's' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AND saet.[IsNavigationEntity] = 0 AND saet.IsSystemEntity = CASE WHEN LEFT(tab.name, 3) = 'Sys' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
WHERE (tab.name NOT IN (SELECT e.[TableName] FROM [SystemAppEntity] e))
    AND (tab.name = @Code)
```

With an output of:

```
EXECUTE [procSystemAppEntity_InsertOrUpdate] 
 @SystemUID = @SystemUID
,@SystemAppCode = @SystemAppCode
,@SystemAppEntityTypeCode = N'App-S'
,@SystemAppEntityUID = '11E347C7-7E69-4555-A6F0-2AFE142FC25F'
,@SystemAppEntityCode = 'Revision'
,@SystemAppEntityName = N'Revision'
,@TableName = N'Revision'
,@TableKeyColumnName = N'RevisionID'
,@TableKeyCodeColumnName = N'RevisionCode'
,@ManagedAssemblyName = N'SomeManagedAssemblyName '
, @ManagedNamespace = N'SomeManagedNamespace '
, @ManagedClassName = 'Revision'
, @IsMultiple = 0
, @IsCodeGenerated = 1 
, @IsIntegratedToStaging = 1
, @IsActive = 1
, @SystemAppUserID = @CreationSystemAppUserID 
;
```

That being said, is there a way that i can maybe write/append the `Output statements` directly to the desired script?

I just want it to add to the bottom of the script. Is this possible and if so, how would i achive this?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT '' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'EXECUTE [procSystemAppEntity_InsertOrUpdate] ' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + ' @SystemUID = @SystemUID' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)  
+ ',@SystemAppCode = @SystemAppCode' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)  
+ ',@SystemAppEntityTypeCode = N''' + saet.[SystemAppEntityTypeCode] + '''' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)  
+ ',@SystemAppEntityUID = '''+ CAST((SELECT NEWID()) AS nvarchar(max)) + '''' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)  
+ ',@SystemAppEntityCode = ''' + tab.name + '''' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)  
+ ',@SystemAppEntityName = N''' + tab.name + '''' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)  
+ ',@TableName = N''' + tab.name + '''' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)  
+ ',@TableKeyColumnName = N''' + tab.name + 'ID''' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)  
+ ',@TableKeyCodeColumnName = N''' + tab.name + 'Code''' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)  
+ ',@ManagedAssemblyName = N''' + CASE WHEN @SystemAppEntityManagedAssemblyName IS NULL THEN '' ELSE @SystemAppEntityManagedAssemblyName END + '''' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)  
+ ', @ManagedNamespace = N''' + CASE WHEN @SystemAppEntityManagedNamespace IS NULL THEN '' ELSE @SystemAppEntityManagedNamespace END + '''' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)  
+ ', @ManagedClassName = ''' + tab.name + '''' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)  
+ ', @IsMultiple = ' + CAST(@IsMultiple AS varchar(1)) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)  
+ ', @IsCodeGenerated = 1' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)  
+ ', @IsActive = 1' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)  
+ ', @SystemAppUserID = @CreationSystemAppUserID ' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + '; 
Insert into table(...) ;' 
FROM sys.tables tab INNER JOIN 
    [SystemAppEntityType] saet ON saet.[IsMultipleEntity] = CASE WHEN RIGHT(tab.name, 1) = 's' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AND saet.[IsNavigationEntity] = 0 AND saet.IsSystemEntity = CASE WHEN LEFT(tab.name, 3) = 'Sys' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
WHERE (tab.name NOT IN (SELECT e.[TableName] FROM [SystemAppEntity] e)) 
    AND (tab.name = @Code)
```

Comment: Please see EDIT: `That being said, is there a way that i can maybe write/append the Output statements directly to the desired script`?

Comment: What did you mean by output statement?

Comment: The statement that you copied generates the actual PROCEDURE statement(See my question). I just want to append it to the bottom of the desired script. The code snippet you have in your answer is a fraction of the statements actually generated. There are about 10 of those statements...

Answer (score 0):

What version of SQL Server are you using?

If you are using SQL Server 2008+ then you can make generate the INSERT scripts via Generate Script utility itself.

In SQL Server 2005 or before (I have tried in SQL 2K also) then there is a pretty good stroed proc which can generate the INSERT script for a given table. Check out http://vyaskn.tripod.com/code/generate_inserts.txt

Comment: Please see EDIT: `That being said, is there a way that i can maybe write/append the Output statements directly to the desired script`?